# How can I run mongosh commands within a podman container via shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, mongo-shell, podman

Maybe it is one layer too much, but maybe you can help me:
How can I run mongosh commands within a podman container via shell script?

I can open the mongosh cli with the following command in my test.sh

test.sh

```
podman exec -it my-app-mongo mongosh
```

But how can I also now e.g. show all databases (`show dbs;`)? Is this even possible?
My bigger goal is to automate creating and provisioning some test tables.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--eval` option to execute a command that you would type on the mongosh CLI:

```
mongosh --eval 'show dbs;' some-db-name
```